# gcc assembler on absolute memory addressing

Tags: assembly

The machine I use is 64-bit 
I wrote assembly code like this:

```
movl $0x12e48ead 0x0804b324
pushl $0x08049103
ret
```

Using AT&T format.
When I compile with it using command line:

```
gcc -m32 -c firecracker.S
```

It turns out errors as follows:

```
firecracker.S: Assembler messages:
firecracker.S:1: Error: junk `0x0804b324' after expression
firecracker.S:1: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `mov'
```

I wonder why this happens. Could anybody help me out? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a comma:

```
movl $0x12e48ead, 0x0804b324
pushl $0x08049103
ret
```

Builds fine.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a syntax error - the syntax for mov is:

```
movl $sourceaddr, $destaddr
```

note the comma and the dollar signs! Of course, sourceaddr and destaddr can also be registers.

The machine being 64-bit shouldn't make a difference, as you've specified `-m32`, which will assemble the code for running on 32-bit platforms.